# Python XML ElementTree tag wildcard

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

How do I add a wildcard to xml TAG search? 
I'm trying to find all children of the current XML node who's tag starts with "MYTAG" using Python's xml.elementTree library.
XML Looks like:

```
ROOT
   FOO
   BAR
   MYTAG1
   MYTAG2
```

I've tried

```
xmlTree = xmlET.parse('XML_FILE')
xmlRoot = xmlTree.getroot()
MYTags = xmlRoot.findall('MYTAG{*}')
```

Using this works correctly but of course only returns one element, not both.

```
xmlRoot.findall('MYTAG1')
```

Comment: Can't you just go with **getchildren()** and check if tag **startswith** ?

Answer (score 4):

As the **xpath** supports are rather limited in **xml**, one alternative is to use **getchildren()** and return the node with tag **startswith**:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from StringIO import StringIO

# sample xml
s = '<root><mytag1>hello</mytag1><mytag2>world!</mytag2><tag3>nothing</tag3></root>'
tree = ET.parse(StringIO(s))
root = tree.getroot()
# using getchildren() within root and check if tag starts with keyword 
print [node.text for node in root.getchildren() if node.tag.startswith('mytag')]
```

Results:

```
['hello', 'world!']
```